# ETL - Add new column from staging to main table

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl

I have an ETL pipeline consisting of load step (AWS Glue ETL script) and a clean up step(pyscopg2 script to move data from Staging to main table and truncate main table in a single transaction). This pipeline runs every 15 mins to full load a PostgreSQL table, says `transactionStats`

The steps I follow are

1. Load records in a staging table, `transactionStats_Staging`
2. `transactionStats` is truncated
3. Records are inserted into `transactionStats` from `transactionStats_Staging`

How do I programmatically detect a new column in the `transactionStats_Staging` table and then add it to the `transactionStats` without dropping and recreating `transactionStats`?

Comment: I’m not sure how anyone could help you if you haven’t explained what ETL tool/process you are using and how you have set up this specific pipeline. Also, if you are truncating the table anyway, why must the solution not also drop/recreate the table?

Comment: Dropping is more expensive than truncating and it will also drop the indexes created on the main table.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using following code in a pyscopg2 script:

```
cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE \"transactionStats\"")
    
cur.execute("""do
        $$
        declare
            f record;
        begin
            for f in SELECT column_name, data_type  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'transactionStats_Staging' except SELECT column_name, data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'transactionStats'
            loop   
                EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE "orderStats_truncateTest" add column IF NOT EXISTS "%s" %s',f.column_name, f.data_type);
            end loop;
        end;
        $$""")
```